# Changing a permalink in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a post in wordpress. I changed its permalink. Previously it was:

```
http://example.com/foo/dogs-so-awesome/
```

and I change the permalink to:

```
http://example.com/foo/dogs/
```

I was expecting the old url to no longer work, but I can still hit it from a web browser and see the page. The new url works, too. Is wordpress doing a redirect here? I'd actually like to remove the old url so it 404s when someone tries to hit it. But I can't find anything in the wordpress admin interface that suggests how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Are you having any redirect plugins? Also check whether it is the post page or any category page.

Comment: No redirect plugins. All I changed was the permalink for the post.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the title of the page? or the permalink?

If you changed the "title" of it, then the page will be titled `dogs`, but the permalink will still be `dogs-so-awesome`. Just underneath the title is the permalink with an "Edit Permalink" option. Use that.

If you want to 404 it, you could use something (possibly the Page Links To plugin) and create a post at `dogs-so-awesome` and 404 it.

Comment: Yes I changed the permalink, not the title. But both urls work, strangely.